# Call webservice with PHP curl

Tags: php, web-services, curl, post, php-curl

I'm currently trying to call a POST web service with the PHP curl. I tried this, but without success (I receive "false", the objective is to receive a string from my web-service):

```
function devis( $data){
    $typeDevis = $data['typeDevis'];
    $compo = $data['compo'];
    $offre = $data['offre'];

    $url = "https://someadress:port/apiname/api/Devis";
    try{
        $fields = array(
            'typeDevis' => $typeDevis,
            'compo' => $compo,
            'offre' => $offre,
        );

        $fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e;
    }
}
```

The link that must be called in POST is for example:

https://someadress:port/apiname/api/Devis?typeDevis=VALUE1&compo=VALUE2&offre=VALUE3

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The URL you posted are passing the data in the query string, suggesting it should be `GET,` not `POST`? Or if it needs to be a POST, then you should add the data to the `$url`-variable so it looks just like the example link you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your function as following:

```
function devis($data){
    $typeDevis = $data['typeDevis'];
    $compo = $data['compo'];
    $offre = $data['offre'];

    $url = "https://someadress:port/apiname/api/Devis";
    try{
        $fields = array(
            'typeDevis' => $typeDevis,
            'compo' => $compo,
            'offre' => $offre,
        );

        // You don't need to use this
        //$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e;
    }
}
```

Try to use proper `curl` syntax and be specific what you want to implement. 
Also it would be better if you'll provide a proper `header` to your API request.

Comment: _"You are passing query parameters within URL itself. Which is not correct in your contex"_ - When I read the question, it's the other way around. Their code is _not_ passing the data in the URL while the example URL they've posted does.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Maybe i got that URL in wrong way.
By the way, that does not matter in the context of my answer.

Comment: IMHO, we should wait until the OP has clarified how the data should be passed and if it really should be a POST.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Indeed, the method MUST be in POST (for security reasons, this has been imposed). The principle is the same as on SoapUI (for those who know) when calling a REST link with POST method.

I'll take a look at the Header.